# Vuex action: best way to resolve nested promises

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, promise, vuex, aws-amplify

I'm new to JavaScript, vue.js and vuex.

I'm trying to maintain a list of image asset URLs in a vuex state array. The assets are in an s3 bucket and I'm using the amplify framework to access it.

As far as I know, I must first list the assets to get the available keys. `Storage.list('assets/')` and then I need to call `Storage.get()` to return the URL. Both of these calls return Promises.

My current vuex module looks like this.

```
state: {
    imageAssets: []
},

getters:{
    collection: state => state.imageAssets,
    // assetByKey: state => key => {

    // }
},

mutations: {
    setImageAssets: (state, imageAssets) => {
        Vue.set(state, 'imageAssets', imageAssets);
    },
    addImageAsset: (state, imageUrl) => {
        state.imageAssets.push(imageUrl);
    }

},

actions: {
    listAssetsS3 : (context) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Storage.list('assets/')
                .then(result => {
                        result.filter(el => /.*\.png/g.test(el.key))
                              .forEach(el => {
                            Storage.get(el.key).then(res => 
                                {
                                    context.commit('addImageAsset', res);
                                    resolve(res)
                                })
                            }) 
                },
                error => {
                    logger.debug('ERROR', error)
                    reject(error);
                })
        })
    },
```

This works, but I'm wondering if this is the correct way to do things. I know that the action needs to return a promise. But I'm a little bit confused about the validity of my resolve commands in this case and also would like to know if my solution is optimal and fits the paradigm of a vue/vuex application?

Any tips, corrections or general advice are extremely welcome.

Many thanks, 
M